# Can you avoid mass assignment issues without using nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, mass-assignment

I have an app with the following relationships between models:

class ContentPartner < User

```
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :videos, through: :events, dependent: :destroy
```

class Video

```
  belongs_to :event
```

class Event

```
  has_many :videos, dependent: :destroy
```

How can I create a new video so that it has the correct :event_id and :content_partner_id passed to it, without using nested resources (which I don't want) or creating a mass-assignement security issue by adding :event_id and :content_partner_id to the Video attr_accessible whitelist?

With my controller like this:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:video][:event_id])   
    @video = @event.videos.create(params[:video])
    if @video.save
      flash[:success] = "Video uploaded!"
      redirect_to session[:return_to]
    else
      flash[:error] = "#{@video.errors.messages}"
      render new_video_path
    end  
  end
```

and no hidden_field in my @videos form, I end up with the error "Couldn't find Event without an ID"

but with:

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>
```

in my form, I get the error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: event_id"

Is there a 3rd way to create a new video that belongs_to an event without using nested resources or compromising on mass assignments risks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can change your hidden_field to:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, @event.id %>
```

And now in your controller, you can access that variable with:

```
Event.find(params[:event_id])
```

This should circumvent the mass-assign error. However, now any malicious user can edit that hidden field and add a video to any event he wishes. To fix this, you should find the event through an association. So if you have a `current_user` or `current_content_partner`, you should find the event like this:

```
current_content_partner.events.find(params[:event_id])
```

Now, a user is only able to access events he owns.

Comment: Hi Ashitaka, you're right, I want to avoid this scenario.  But equally don't want nested routes if I can help it.

Comment: Ok, in that case, give a little more information about your app. Who can create a Video? Is it the ContentPartner? And the ContentPartner can only create videos and add them to Events he owns, right? Well, do you have a current_content_partner? Normally, you'd have a current_user (which is an authenticated user), but in this case I'm not sure. The reason I'm asking is because then you could do something like: `current_content_partner.events.find(params[:event_id])` and now a malicious user would only be able to access events he owns.

Comment: Your suggestion of finding the event id through another association, in this case the authenticated current_user, is a good one and works.  However I've ultimately decided that using nested routes for just the new and create actions is the best option after all.

Comment: If you could update your answer with the suggestion from your previous comment I will choose it as the correct one, because it most directly reflects the question I asked, which was to avoid nested routes and mass assignment of event_id. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error

1) "Couldn't find Event without an ID" : might be because `params[:video][:event_id]` is nil

2) "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: event_id" : because you are doing

`@video = @event.videos.create(params[:video])`
and `params[:video]` contains `event_id` as `params[:video][:event_id]` where `event_id` is a protected attribute

Setting a protected attribute (here `event_id`) through `hidden_field` is definitely not recommended, since any user can edit the value for that hidden field from the UI using any developer tool as said by @Ashitaka

You should use `nested resources` to get `event_id` directly from the URL.

Comment: Thanks Amit, thanks.  I'm trying to avoid nested resources as I don't want urls of /event/:event_id/video/:id (even with friendly urls). However, is it possible to have the nested resource only for the 'create' action?  And if so, how would that look in routes? Thanks